# meaning of "as is true"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In the oral tradition, these types face archetypal predicaments, **as is
>   true**, for example, of the protagonist of *Borom Sarrat*, who has no name
>   and is recognizable instead by his trade-he is a street merchant-and
>   by the difficulties he encounters but is unable to overcome.

In this sentence, what does "**as is true**" means? Is it a popular idiom?

I looked up for idiom "as is true", but there was no idiom like this. Is "as is true" means "like it is the case"? So the whole sentence kinda means

> In the oral tradition,  these types face archetypal predicaments, **and it is also the case for** the protagonist of Borom Sarrat. The protagonist also go through some archetypal predicaments (or *hardships*).

Comment: If you remove the "for example" does it make more sense for you? "*As is true of the protagonist...*"

Comment: Please tell us what your own research tells you about this usage. Are you familiar with the many uses of the English word _as?_

Comment: I did look up for idiom "as is true", but there was no idiom like this. Is "as is true" means "like it is the case"? So the whole sentence kinda means " these types face archetypal predicaments, and it is also the case for the protagonist of Borom Sarrat. The protagonist also go through some archetypal predicaments (hardships)"

Comment: There is an implied "it": "as it is true".  Your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this type of syntax, "as is" means "which is".

Hence, as you suggested in the comments, "as is true of" means "which is true of".

What follows the expression is an example of the general statement made.

> For birds that are able to migrate across continents, as is true of certain songbirds that fly across the Sahara, every oasis is invaluable.

In your example, the protagonist of *Borom Sarrat* is offered as an example of "types" that face archetypal predicaments.

Note that it's also sometimes used to mean "which is *also* true of":

> — "She's so industrious but she has no direction."
>   
> — "As is true of so many people our age."

But I would avoid this usage in more formal settings, where "as is true of", "as is the case for", and so on are used to introduce an example illustrating a general statement, as I said above.